# How to transform the "Date" column

Tags: excel

I have the following problem:
In the "Date" column I have about 380.000 entries with the date format like this:
https://i.ibb.co/TMGVyzN/Clipboard01.jpg

Instead of 201207 I obviously need the format to be 07/2012.

I already tried to fix it by formatting the cells but I can't find a proper date format. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they all are the same, I suggest creating a new column with the formula =TRUNC(A1/100) which gives you the year, then a second column with =MOD(A1;100);

Now you can concatenate those two: =CONCATENATE(C1;"/"; B1)

[image]

Comment: I did it with the LEFT and RIGHT functions, but I didn't know how to concatenate the 3 elements. Thank you!

Comment: Left and right is for strings, what I proposed is for numbers. Whatever works is best - I tend to stick to numbers whenever possible. It reduces the risk of unrecognised blanks etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`=RIGHT(B1,2) & "/" &LEFT(B1,4)`